# Standard FILE objects in c

Tags: c, file

There are standard FILE objects, stdin, stdout, stderr.

Can I create my own FILE objects similar to the standard FILE objects?

Comment: "Similar to standard FILE object" : similar in which way ? What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: C does not have objects, so there's that for starters. You can "create" references to files by calling functions that open files or work with files for instance - `fopen`.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum of course does C have objects. This wording is even used in the standard. It doesn't have objects having (in an OOP-style) functionality *attached* to them, but that's easily doable using some conventions.

Comment: It really depends on what you mean by "similar".  If you mean, "create pointers of type `FILE *` that I can read from and write to", then yes, you absolutely can, as discussed in the answer by @paddy.  If you mean "Arrange for there to be new, preopened file pointers just like `stdin` and `stdout` that are automatically there, that I don't have to explicitly open or even declare", you either can't do that, or it would require modifying the compiler and standard libraries.

Comment: Kindly refer to metastackoverflow to learn how to ask questions and avoid getting downvotes .. You are quite new here so would strongly suggest you. And not downvoting because you are quite new

Comment: This article is helpful, for the second point made by @spt025 : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use `fopen` or related functions to open a file, or `popen` to open a pipe.  They return a `FILE*` which you can use for I/O.

- [fopen reference](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html)
- [popen refernece](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes..
You can do this if you are willing to.

Refer to this Link for further reference

[Build your own library in C](http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/Building-a-library.html)